# Biq Query regex_replace error (\? vs \\?)

Tags: sql, regex, google-bigquery

I am having issues understanding what's wrong with this regex: `\?.*`

```
 select REGEXP_REPLACE(longstringcolumn, '\?.*', '') as newstring from tablename
```

My example string aka 'longstring' has '?' character, and I am trying to match everything trailing '?' (including '?' itself).

I have checked my regexpr in online tools and my regex seems to be working.

### Edit

Thanks guys for being so quick, 
Here's a sample string (it's a url):

**http://example.com/one/two/three?lang=en&region=CN**

*I am trying to strip off everything after '?'. So this part:*

**?lang=en&region=CN**

This is the error I am being returned: Failed to parse regular expression "?": no argument for repetition operator: ?

I am really leaning towards this being a simple escape character issue but I can't figure it out somehow.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: also, I am using this inside of another regexp_replace().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#standardSQL
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(longstringcolumn, '\\?.*', '') AS newstring 
FROM tablename
```

or

```
#standardSQL
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(longstringcolumn, r'\?.*', '') AS newstring 
FROM tablename
```

example below

```
#standardSQL
WITH tablename AS (
  SELECT 'is this a question?abc ' AS longstringcolumn UNION ALL
  SELECT 'this is not a question' union all
  SELECT'http://example.com/one/two/three?lang=en&region=CN'
)
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(longstringcolumn, r'\?.*', '') AS newstring 
FROM tablename
```

with result as (where ? and all trailing chars are removed)

```
Row newstring    
1   is this a question   
2   this is not a question
```

Hope this shows what was wrong with your original query